# SPML (spatial panel models): Error in lag.listw | unbalanced panels

Tags: r, geospatial, panel-data, plm, spml

I am making spatial panel models from the splm library but I cannot make a fixed or random effects model because it comes out that it is an unbalanced panel.

## Data

[data](https://mega.nz/file/coQkjRib#WlmMuoJDG1BROJxnCAgFw_Zp-2SAW-jtSUOgeQizeC0) and [shp files](https://mega.nz/file/0ppCHKjS#Uq871u3vJoO9_tFFItZny1LGZ1zwXe-lDLWFzBd0-LI)

## Reproducible example

```
library(dplyr)
library(Hmisc)
library(sf)
library(plm)
library(splm)
library(spdep)
data = read.csv("data.csv", colClasses=c(id="factor"))
map = st_read("nxparroquias.shp")
colnames(map)[1] = "id"

balanced = data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  #drop_na() %>% 
  filter(all(c(2013:2018) %in% year)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(id %in% unique(map$id))

map = map %>% 
  filter(id %in% unique(balanced$id))
pt = spdep::poly2nb(map)
ptw = spdep::nb2listw(pt, zero.policy = TRUE)

describe(balanced$id)
#balanced$id 
#n  missing distinct 
#5832        0      972 

describe(map$id)
#map$id 
#n  missing distinct 
#972        0      972 

#checks if the data are balanced
plm::is.pbalanced(balanced$id,balanced$year)
#[1] TRUE

p_balanced = pdata.frame(balanced, index = c("id", "year"))  #same issues
```

### Pooling

```
md1 = splm::spml(data = balanced,
                 y ~ x1+x2+x3, 
                 index =  c("id", "year"),
                 zero.policy = TRUE,
                 model = "pooling",
                 listw = ptw)
summary(md1)

#ML panel with , spatial error correlation 
#
#Call:
#  spreml(formula = formula, data = data, index = index, w = listw2mat(listw), 
#         w2 = listw2mat(listw2), lag = lag, errors = errors, cl = cl, 
#         zero.policy = TRUE)
#
#Residuals:
#  Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#-14.860  -3.213   0.539   0.003   3.194  13.181 
#
#Error variance parameters:
#  Estimate Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)    
#rho 0.087841   0.019622  4.4767 7.58e-06 ***
#  
#  Coefficients:
#  Estimate Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept)  5.1373431  0.0972298 52.8371 < 2.2e-16 ***
#  x1           0.0423977  0.0098276  4.3141 1.602e-05 ***
#  x2           0.1109780  0.0083800 13.2432 < 2.2e-16 ***
#  x3          -0.0444174  0.0096522 -4.6018 4.189e-06 ***
#  ---
#  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

### FE

```
md2 = splm::spml(data = balanced,
                 y ~ x1+x2+x3, 
                 index =  c("id", "year"),
                 zero.policy = TRUE,
                 model = "within",
                 listw = ptw)
```

**With reproducible example Fixed effects**

> Error in lag.listw(listw, u, zero.policy = zero.policy) :
> object lengths differ

**With my original data**

> Error in spfeml(formula = formula, data = data, index = index, listw = listw, :
> Estimation method unavailable for unbalanced panels

### RE

**with random effects**

> Error in .C64("aplsb1", SIGNATURE = c(SS$signature, SS$signature, "double", :
> NAs in argument 7 and 'NAOK = FALSE' (dotCall64)

Comment: you may want to try this question on stackGIS as well

Comment: Can you please reupload the "data" file. I am not able to download it.

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I'm struggling with the same. Any advice would be appreciated!!

Comment: @AdrianaCastilloCastillo, Me too, so pls post if you solve(d) this!  Only a guess, but I wonder if it's an under/overflow error.  For either half of my time periods, the splm resolves.  With ~ 3/4 of the time periods, the request fails in < 5 minutes with exactly same message as in RE above.  I am testing with a pared-down dataset of (up to) 17 time periods, ~ 500 cells and 3 predictors - not big, although a bit much for direct posting.

Comment: @InColorado : I found that there is an option of doing it in Stata: https://www.stata.com/meeting/uk13/abstracts/materials/uk13_hughes.pdf

Were you able to run it with the 17 periods you are mentioning? Sorry if I misunderstood, but is it an issue about capacity? Maybe you can try with parallel processing.